# Polymorphic "flip" fails in 7.10

Tags: haskell, ghc

The [monomorphic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monomorphic) library contains the following snippet (which should hopefully compile in 7.8):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, ExistentialQuantification, FlexibleContexts, GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes, PolyKinds, RankNTypes, TypeFamilies       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances                           #-}

class Monomorphicable k where
  type MonomorphicRep k :: *

withPolymorphic :: Monomorphicable k
               => MonomorphicRep k -> (forall a. k a -> b) -> b
withPolymorphic k trans = undefined

-- | Flipped version of 'withPolymorphic'.
liftPoly :: Monomorphicable k
         => (forall a. k a -> b) -> MonomorphicRep k -> b
liftPoly = flip withPolymorphic
```

However in 7.10, GHC complains:

```
Couldn't match type ‘k2 a0 -> b’ with ‘forall (a :: k0). k1 a -> b’
    Expected type: MonomorphicRep k2 -> (k2 a0 -> b) -> b
      Actual type: MonomorphicRep k1
                   -> (forall (a :: k0). k1 a -> b) -> b
    Relevant bindings include
      liftPoly :: (forall (a :: k). k2 a -> b) -> MonomorphicRep k2 -> b
        (bound at Data/Type/Monomorphic.hs:45:1)
    In the first argument of ‘flip’, namely ‘withPolymorphic’
    In the expression: flip withPolymorphic
```

Of course if I changed the definition of `liftPoly` to

```
liftPoly a b = withPolymorphic b a
```

then 7.10 is happy. What's going on here? Is 7.10 supposed to be stricter when dealing with polymorphic functions somehow? It doesn't appear to be the monomorphism restriction since everything has a signature.

Comment: Impredicative types aren't really supported, I think. So it's not too surprising that something related to them has changed. But: try annotating the type of `flip`, and I bet it will work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type of `flip` is

```
flip :: (x -> y -> z) -> (y -> x -> z)
```

To type check `liftPoly`, we have to instantiate the variable `y` at the polymorphic type `forall a. k a -> b`. This is an instance of impredicative polymorphism.

As the page at https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ImpredicativePolymorphism says,

> We've made various attempts to support impredicativity, so there is a flag `-XImpredicativeTypes`. But it doesn't work, and is absolutely unsupported. If you use it, you are on your own; I make no promises about what will happen.

So, don't be too surprised when the behavior of `ImpredicativeTypes` changes between versions of GHC.